How to, purposefully, delay the response from minio bucket
I am working on project where I am sending read requests on minIO bucket. I want to setup minio to delay its response to some specific time interval. How can I do so?
I want minio to delay its response by some time interval.

You have to inspect the source code and see how to do that ( it's Go). Why this requirement?  Just curious...

In my project, I have to handle scenario when bucket doesn't send response within a time interval.
